# Java: encrypted data over Socket

Tags: java, sockets, encryption, cryptography

I'm trying to send encrypted data over a Socket.

I built a Server and a Client, and I can successfully exchange data, with a typical *(This is a client example, works the same on the server)* :

```
int count = 0;
byte[] buffer = new buffer[4096];

while ((count = fileInputStream.read(buffer)) >= 0) 
{
    outToServer.write(buffer, 0, count);
    outToServer.flush();
}
```

I also have a method that takes a `byte[]` and a key, and returns a `byte[]` encrypted with **AES 128bit**. Another method decrypts in the same manner.

Now, how would I send encrypted data over the `Socket`?
I ran into a lot of issues since the size of the encrypted buffer is not the same as the plain buffer. So for example, I load `4096` bytes from the file, encrypt them and end up with `4112`.
That number is not optimal for transfer. I can't break it up since clearly the server needs to read the blocks "whole" - as they were encrypted - or it won't be able to decrypt.

Even if I first encrypt the whole file, then send it, I still have to encrypt it block by block, and the blocks are gonna be broken up when I read it back to decrypt it.

Obviously the server cannot know the padding size of an encrypted block to begin with (before receiving anything), so it will always read 4096 bytes at a time.

What can I do?

Comment: What do you mean by "optimal number for transfer"?

Comment: Specify the payload size. Your server can adjust the buffer if needed, or simply read multiple `0-4096` chunks until the entire payload has been obtain. The `4096` is the amount of data that can be read in a single read, that doesn't mean all payload must fit within that range.

Comment: @Andremoniy Looking around here on SO I found that everyone suggests to move data in blocks of 4096, 8192, .. etc.

Comment: @Vince Emigh  The payload cannot be in the heap all at once, so it has to be encrypted and decrypted in blocks, as they come. then they're written to file. If I send a 4096 block, I cut out bytes and the server won't be able to decrypt.

Comment: Have a look at `CipherInputStream` and `CipherOutputStream`. Don't flush inside loops.

Comment: NB 'Not optimal for transfer' is erroneous. TCP will segment the data any way it likes anyway. Don't worry about trying to outthink TCP. You won't.

Comment: @AJNeufeld You don't need `DataOutputStream` for that. `OutputStream.write()` will already do that, for any output stream.

Comment: @EJP Ack!  My bad!  I thought the `DataInput` and `DataOutput` interfaces included primitive array support.

Answer (score 0):

If you're set on the idea of sending data in 4096-byte chunks, you could just read the unencrypted data in slightly smaller chunks (probably 4095 bytes, if your padding works the way I think it does), and then send your padded 4096-byte chunks over the wire.

It's true that the size of the unencrypted plaintext and the encrypted ciphertext are not the same, but encrypting any two equal-length plaintexts should yield you equal-length ciphertexts.  If you always encrypt plaintexts of the same size, then the size of encrypted ciphertexts you're sending over your socket should always be the same.  So as an alternative to the above, you could continue reading your file in chunks of 4096, and just tell the receiving buffer to expect 4112 bytes.

You didn't mention which mode of AES you're using (I suspect CBC) or which padding scheme you're using (I suspect PKCS#7), so I'm not exactly sure how the padding works in your scheme, but I'm guessing your scheme is being padded out to the next multiple of 16 bytes (with a full 16 bytes being added if it's already a multiple of 16).  So you should be able to read your file in chunks of 4095 bytes, or at worst 4080 bytes, and they'll be padded out to 4096.

I also encourage you to switch to GCM mode, which (1) doesn't need padding, and (2) gives you authentication in addition to encryption.

Comment: GCM doesn't pad the encryption, but the JCA API appends the authtag to the ciphertext which effectively expands the ciphertext. And CBC usually requires you send the IV along with the ciphertext, while GCM can use a counter that doesn't need to be transmitted if -- and only if -- your data transport is ordered and reliable like TCP but not UDP.

Answer (score 0):

> What can I do?

You don't have to do anything. Regardless of what you send, TCP will segmentize it and IP will packetise it any way it likes. At the receiving end TCP is a byte stream, not a messaging system.